# If the answer type id entered in myinput field is 1, I want the answers to be saved to the table by adding commas between them. How to do that?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

At the moment, the function of my code works as follows, if `answer type == 1`, it only allows text to be entered, if it is 2, it only takes numbers, but besides that, if the type is 1, I want to show the given texts on my screen by separating them with commas.

```
@model TourCms.DataAccess.ViewModels.SurveyCreateViewModel
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
    <!-- Basic Layout -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Create</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form method="post" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Survey">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="Question"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" asp-for="Question">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Question" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="AnswerTypeId"></label>
                                <select class="form-control" asp-for="AnswerTypeId" id="AnswerTypeId" >
                                    <option value="1">Text</option>
                                    <option value="2">Number</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="Answers"></label>
                                <input id="answer-input" class="form-control" asp-for="Answers">
                                <span asp-validation-for="Answers" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label" asp-for="Language"></label>
                                <select class="form-control" asp-for="Language">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="EN">English</option>
                                    <option value="TR">Turkish</option>
                                    <option value="FR">France</option>
                                    <option value="DE">Deutsche</option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Language" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var answerInput = document.getElementById('answer-input');
        var answerTypeSelect = document.getElementById('AnswerTypeId');

        checkAnswerType();

        answerTypeSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
            checkAnswerType();
        });

        function checkAnswerType() {
            var answerType = answerTypeSelect.value;
             answerInput.value = '';              
        }

        answerInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
            if (answerTypeSelect.value === '1') {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z çÇğĞıİöÖşŞüÜ]/g, '');
            } else {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the answer type id entered in my input field is 1, I want the added answers to be printed to the table by adding commas between them, how can I provide this?

Comment: What do you mean by "printed to the table"? What table?

Comment: can you clarify more? the question is a bit misunderstanding...

Comment: what I want is only to show the answers by putting commas between them